# Logstash Aggregrate not working as expected

Tags: logstash, kibana, filebeat

am using simple logstash aggregrate function as advised from elastic site, but i found its not working with same logs with logstash config input and output PFB.

Logs:
INFO - 12345 - TASK_START - start
INFO - 12345 - SQL - sqlQuery1 - 12
INFO - 12345 - SQL - sqlQuery2 - 34
INFO - 12345 - TASK_END - end

Am not getting expected output, am i missing any config in pipelines.?

Comment: What is your pipeline? Are you using pipeline.workers set to 1? What is the desired output and what is your output? Update your question with these information.

Comment: Hi, am adding the same config as per elastic site, but its not working as it says aggregrate exception.

Comment: Update your question with your config and your error, you need to provide more information about your problem directly in your question.

Comment: Hi, you can refer this site, this same code am applying in my logstash but am not getting exact output
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html

Comment: If you follow the example and it is not working then you could have a mistaken in your configuration that you are not seeing, as I said update your question with your configuration and a sample message, there is no way to know what is happening without these information. Also confirm that you are running logstash with just only 1 worker, this is the main cause of problems with the aggregate filter, it only works if you use pipeline.workers set to 1.